# Angularjs form.$dirty

Tags: angularjs

I'm able to find form data is changed or not using $dirty.

ex: I changed text box or drop down and then $dirty become true. If I reverted to old data still it is true. I need to know if my changes are reverted or not. Do we have any property in Angularjs? If property is true I want to enable save button otherwise it should be disable.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController

I need to implement around 10 pages and each page has 10 text boxes and a couple of drop downs. So I don't want track each control manually in my pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this module: https://github.com/betsol/angular-input-modified

From the README file:

> This Angular.js module adds additional properties and methods to the
>   ngModel and ngForm controllers, as well as CSS classes to the
>   underlying form elements to provide end-user with facilities to detect
>   and indicate changes in form data.
>
> This extra functionality allows you to provide better usability with
>   forms. For example, you can add decorations to the form elements that
>   are actually changed. That way, user will see what values has changed
>   since last edit.
>
> Also, you can reset an entire form or just a single field to it's
>   initial state (cancel all user edits) with just a single call to the
>   reset() method or lock new values (preserve new state) just by calling
>   overloaded $setPristine() method.

**DISCLAIMER:** I haven't tried it myself and I notice the author overwrites the `ngModel` directive instead of [adding a decorator](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#decorator), which could be dangerous...but at the very least, you can look at the source and get an idea of how to write your own service or directive with similar functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Even though it does not follow the usage of `$dirty`, but an implementation similar to this might be helpful for you in the case of a *Save* button on update.

Inside your html:

```
<form name="testForm" ng-controller="ExampleController" ng-submit=" save()">
  <input ng-model="val" ng-change="change()"/>
  <button ng-disabled="disableSave">Save</button>
</form>
```

Inside your controller:

```
.controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.disableSave = true;  // Keep save button disabled initially

  $scope.val = 'Initial';  // Initial value of the variable

  var copyVal = $scope.val; // Copy Initial value into a temp variable 

  $scope.change = function() {
    $scope.disableSave = $scope.val === copyVal;
  };

  $scope.save = function() {
    // Save the updated value (inside $scope.val)
    console.log($scope.val);

    // Re-disable the input box (on successful updation)
    copyVal = $scope.val;
    $scope.disableSave = true;

  };
}]);
```

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/eb8wngEIVYw3dLA43Kx7?p=preview) is a working plunkr for the same.

Comment: I need to implement around 10 pages and each page has 10 text boxes and a couple of drop downs. So I don't want track each control in my pages. That's why I'm asking angularjs property.